# Android getting location and setting text Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am using a great location class found here on SO to get my location via network or gps. It works and gives me the location in the Log.i() output, however, when I try and add these variables to a textView I get a nullpointerexception.

Here is my Emergency class:

```
     public class EmergencyActivity extends NavigationActivity {
    private TextView tvYourLocation;
    public String wxUrl;
    public String latlon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //show no back arrow
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency);

        LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location){
                //Got the location!
                latlon = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "<br/> Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
                Log.i("URL",latlon);
                tvYourLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todaysReport);
                tvYourLocation.setText(Html.fromHtml("<strong>Your current location is: <br/>" + latlon +"</strong>"));
            }
        };
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);



    }
}
```

I am using this class for myLocation:

```
public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }

}
```

...found here: [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

How do I find this Null?

Here is my log output:

```
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.backcountryskiers.avalanche.conditions/com.backcountryskiers.avalanche.conditions.EmergencyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at com.backcountryskiers.avalanche.conditions.EmergencyActivity.onCreate(EmergencyActivity.java:43)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-06 22:00:52.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19936):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Looks like the error is in EmergencyActivity.java:43. YOu haven't posted that class I guess/

Comment: @AndroSelva Thanks Andro :) updated. I was trying it in the weather class also to see if something else what up...

Comment: what do you have on line 43 in  EmergencyActivity.java?

Comment: I had this line incorrect... tvYourLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvYourLocation);

Comment: @AndroSelva. Yes, how do i give you credit for answering / helping me?

Comment: well its fine.. I didnt answer your question though. No props.. :)

Comment: Well, thanks for looking at it. I guess it's time to go to bed. lol